# How to use containerd to import images to azure container register

Tags: azure, docker, azure-aks, azure-container-registry, containerd

I currently use kubectl ctr to import my image files into the containerd registry for my local vm k3s setup.

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/k3s ctr image import file.image
```

However, i am now trying to use azure kubernetes service (aks) going forward but i still don't want to use docker. Most documentations i found online on pushing images to AKS involved using docker registry which is not an option for me for now.

My question is:
How can i use ctr or any other containerd operation to push ***file.image*** to the azure container registry without involving docker or docker hub. Is there a way to transfer images from my local containerd registry to the azure container registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use ctr to manage your container images with the below functionalities including push and tag actions that you are looking for

Please have a look at documentation;
https://www.mankier.com/8/ctr#images,_image,_i

[image]